# Where to learn Linux user administration for a Web server?

Tags: linux

**Note: Skip ahead to the bold & italic paragraph down there if you don't like tl;dr.**

Alright, so I'm a huge computer geek, have been making websites since I was kid, etc. I am now moving to a dedicated server solution with Ubuntu, but for me, Linux user administration in particular has always been a very foreign concept.

But, probably because everyone thinks it's too simple and everyone knows about it already, I haven't been successful at finding a complete reference for the user system in Linux. The best I've had is a few concepts here and there and maybe a few poorly explained shell commands, but never anything that made me grasp the subject.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to make a VPS (with Linode, it's already done and all) with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, with a few users that may only have limited shell access or none at all, but still require it to do SFTP.

Here are a list of things I have been trying to do/comprehend without ever finding good written resources for:

- Get an overview of all the users currently on the system (for management purposes)
- Disable root and enable administration through another user
- Create users with limited sets of permissions (such as only being able to see their own home folder)
- Create users that can FTP in over SSH but not login through an SSH console
- Manage folder and file permissions
- **Understand all this**

The last part is especially important. The problem is most guides explain things in ways that are incomprehensible from a total stranger's perspective. The commands work, but I still don't understand what's happening, which is not good.

Example of what I mean (from Linode Library):

> To create normal users, use the
>   adduser command in the following form:
>
> adduser [username]
>
> With the adduser command you can also
>   be more specific with regards to what
>   the user's home directory and default
>   shell will be.
>   The following command creates the user
>   "squire" in the groups "morris" and
>   "leader":
>
> adduser --home /home/squire \         ## specify a conventional home directory
>           --shell /bin/bash \              ## specify bash as the default shell
>           --ingroup morris leader squire   ## specify to which groups this user should belong

While this all alright, there's a staggering lack of information for a newbie like me, like, what happens after running the adduser command, why /bin/bash, what's the syntax for he ingroup command, where is the username in the second list of commands, etc.

Well, you get the picture. The typical Linux system admin will tell me to RTFM without telling me how to do even just that. I need something that explains to me what's happening. Having a list of definitions and then jumping in is just no good because these definitions are totally out of context.

**The Actual Question**

***Does anyone know about a Linux Administration Book/Article/Whatever that would provide enough details on user administration as to do the equivalent of a teacher answering most of the questions students could possibly come up with during a course.***

I'm usually not that helpless, but for some reason, the Linux user system is very cryptic to me and 100% of the help available I have found has proven cryptic as well. Anyone care to light up my path of learning?

Comment: Well I went to Chapters and found the thing I was looking for. It's a book called Unix and Linus System Administration Handbook (Fourth Edition) and it's awesome! It has lengthy and clear explanations on how everything works, and for more than Ubuntu (Unix in general, SUSE and RedHat, and other Unixes, namely HP-UX, Solaris and AIX.

I'll leave the question open though, just in case someone else finds something better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did and recommend:

1. Learn the [basic linux commands](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20basics).
2. Learn about the filesystem structure. *What are the files stored in /etc?*
3. Learn about linux permissions. *-rwx-r-x-r-x what?!*
4. Learn about linux processes. *There's demon.. eh.. daemons in linux?!*
5. Briefly read up the popular servers that can be run on linux. *Apache, MySQL, DNS, NFS, Samba, Squid - I have it all!*
6. Try to set up a web or fileserver. *Seriously, do it.*
7. Learn a little about shell scripting. *Can you automate your daily work?*
8. Learn to use the **man** command - I use it every day.
9. If you don't remember exactly what the command was, type the first letter or two of the command and press Tab twice, this will list all commands starting with the given letter.

Playing around, moving files, starting and stopping processes, setting up Apache etc. is the best way to learn in my opinion.

Comment: Get an old PC, slap in Linux (eg: Redhat, Ubuntu) and use the terminal application (ie: shell). Nothing beats learning it hands on and if you are running LAMP services, learn how to debug those error messages in var/log

Comment: dont get an old pc, get a virtualbox

Comment: This is the best answer.

Like programming, I have found that there is no one resource which can explain how to manage Linux servers in a single read. Trying to learn Linux with a book is tantamount to reading a dictionary to learn a language.

All the concepts you are going to learn require knowledge of all the other pieces, so you have no choice but to start somewhere, try things, and persevere. Eventually, your knowledge will culminate into something.

For instance, I now manage and develop multiple apps and machines on AWS, and much of that knowledge has grown organically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working through the [Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) and I find it to be super approachable and straightforward.  The pace and tone are just right for someone who is serious but doesn't know anything about Linux.  It's written by the guy behind [linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org) (also a great resource) and to my knowledge covers everything you just mentioned (I'm only on page 125 of about 500, though).  It's also setup in a format that lets you play along in the shell as he explains things.  I can't recommend this book enough!

Answer (score 0):

I have a (very old albeit) copy of 'the linux Bible' that i find priceless.

Comment: https://newtechtalks.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/useful-linux-commands-for-server-admin/